# SourceTree SSH options on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm trying to connect to GitHub through [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) on OS X using SSH. Even though I can connect fine command line, I can't seem to work with any repo through SSH in SourceTree with the error:

> Permission denied (publickey).

All the help topics I have found online suggest configuring the SSH client in SourceTree. However, all of that documentation is for the Windows version. **How can I access the SSH Preferences on the OS X version of SourceTree?**

Answer (score 34):

It was hard to find this answer, but it looks like the way to do this is to just add the ssh key to your keychain in Mac OS. I found an answer here: https://wiki.hpcc.msu.edu/display/hpccdocs/Adding+a+Private+Key+to+Your+Mac+OSX+Keychain

From the link:

> On Mac OSX, the native SSH client can use the built-in keychain directly. To add your private key to the keychain simply use the command:
>
> ```
> ssh-add -K /path/of/private/key
> ```
>
> As an example if your private key is stored at ~/.ssh and is named id_rsa, you would use the command:
>
> ```
> ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
> ```
>
> You will then be prompted for your passcode, which will be stored in your keychain. After this you should be ready for a password-less login.

After I added my SSH key, SourceTree started authenticating correctly.

**1/18/2017 EDIT:** Apparently OSX Sierra made it so you don't get your keys back when you login, so you'll have to do this every time you start your computer. BUT, there's a nice way to fix this from the Apple stack exchange: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically

Just follow the steps in the answer with "Update Jan 2017"

Comment: `-K` is now depricated and you should use `--apple-use-keychain` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to google this as well, since adding custom SSH Keys with OpenSSH is available in the Tools section in SourceTree(ST) for Windows.

Although I was able to ssh -T successfully from terminal, ST for Mac was denying access.

Finally, I thought of adding the keys to my agent again. Now, when I checked the list of identities added - there were none (ssh-add -l).
Just add your ssh key to the agent and ST will automatically pick your key and grant access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, except the error message I got sounded:

```
   Permission denied (publickey,password)
```

Instead of trying and erring with lots of different answers, I went after the root cause of the problem. I found out that the ssh configuration file, which is `~/.ssh/config`, plays a role in this matter. In my case it contained two records:

```
# --- ssh to OUNL  ---
Host *
    HostName 145.20.188.96
    User sjo
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/sjo00577/.ssh/id_ou_rsa
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
# --- Sourcetree Generated ---
Host *
    HostName github.com
    User stefjoosten
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/sjo00577/.ssh/id_rsa
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
# ----------------------------
```

When I swapped both records, ssh to github worked again, but ssh to 145.20.188.96 did not work anymore. This prompted me to read a [manual for the ssh config file](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/). Apparently, the first occurrence of `host *` is used for every host, so the github host is shadowed entirely. The following solution solved the problem: Just let the first record refer only to the designated host instead of all hosts:

```
# --- ssh naar OUNL  ---
Host 145.20.188.96
    User sjo
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/sjo00577/.ssh/id_ou_rsa
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
# --- Sourcetree Generated ---
Host *
    HostName github.com
    User stefjoosten
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/sjo00577/.ssh/id_rsa
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
# ----------------------------
```

This works fine and it solved the problem. Even better is to confine github to the correct host too. So I guess that you want to look for the problem in `~/.ssh/config`. I reckon that this solution will also work in situations other than Sourcetree on MacBook only.